# Using the confidence intervals to improve predictive model success rate

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, matlab

I'm trying to build a binomial predictive model based on glm.
My overall prediction is very low, in the order of 60%. But when I go for the datapoints that have the both boundaries in one side, for example lower bound upper bound and the estimated value all 3 fall under or above 0.5, my prediction success rate clearly improves.

In doing this I have to sacrifice a big part of my data, still I want to know if it's statistically valid to do what I just explained. Am I cherry picking in any way?
P.S: I use the entire dataset and not the chosen part for training my model.